# Shopify not able to add item to existing metafields

Tags: shopify

I want to add new item to the existing metafields section from shopify admin : https://storeurl.com/admin/metafields/product
But unable to add the same since its coming disabled. What is wrong and how can i update? Please help.

[Screenshot attached here for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcK4Y.png)

Comment: I didn't even know that this was a thing already! About time that Shopify started adding some admin UI support for metafields!

Answer (score 0):

From my quick testing, it looks as though at this time of writing (2021-12-03) Shopify's new metafield definitions feature allows you to *create* metafield definitions but not *edit* them.

I just ran a quick test and took a screen recording of metafield-definition creation followed by attempting to edit:
[Screen Recording (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/Y0CG8d8lvE0)

It looks like setting up your option list is, for now at least, something that you have to get right on the first try. Hopefully this will be remedied soon, but for now it looks like you would have to delete and re-create your metafield definition in order to update the options list.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022-06-14 not only can you not edit a metafield ... you also can't delete it and re-create it with the same name. It's absolutely ridiculous, what are the chances that users will create and select all the correct options the first time for hundreds of metafields? Shopify sort this out.